# How can i play animation one time only?

Tags: jquery, viewport, attr, animated-gif

I replace a jpg file with an animated gif file when the div container appears in the viewport. It works. Important : the gif file has no loop.
My problem : when you scroll again, even a bit, up or down, the replacement play again.
Is there a simple solution to stop this event after the first time replacement ?
Thanks

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
 
 var $window = $(window);
 var $elem = $(".animated")

  function isScrolledIntoView($elem, $window) {
   var docViewTop = $window.scrollTop();
   var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $window.height();

   var elemTop = $elem.offset().top;
   var elemBottom = elemTop + $elem.height();

   return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
  }


 $(document).on("scroll", function () {
  if (isScrolledIntoView($elem, $window)) {
   $("#graph1").attr("src","images/graphsSECHE_500x500_noloop2.gif");
  }
  
 });
});
```

Comment: set a global bool and set it to true or false based on whether you have played the video or not and then add that to your check

Comment: or if it's literally just one element that's changing, you could unbind the scroll event handler on the document once it's been used once?

Comment: or do similar to Pete's comment, but you could assign the data to the element itself using the data functionality of jquery, then check that per element. That then allows many elements to be assigned independently.

Comment: try to use jquery's stop() function like this .stop(true, true) after your animation.

Comment: @Shao Khan, There's no jquery animation happening here.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize a boolean value at page load, for example:

```
var played = false;
```

Then check if your animation as already been played, and don't forget to actually set it true inside the if by:

```
if (isScrolledIntoView($elem, $window) && played === false) {
    $("#graph1").attr("src","images/graphsSECHE_500x500_noloop2.gif");
    played = true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very very much DocWeird : it works with a var played = true

Comment: Haha, yes, you're correct - an error on my part. I was a bit in a hurry. Answer corrected.